# How to prove that, if two numbers are equal $\mod2$ and$\mod3$ ,they are equal$\mod 6 $?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I was wondering if it could be proved without using the Chinese remainder theorem, arithmetically.

Thank you

Comment: If $2\mid a-b$ and $3\mid a-b$, then $6\mid a-b$

Comment: Technically you don't need the full power of the Chinese remainder theorem. You can make an argument from a simple lemma involving prime divisors and/or prime factorizations.

Answer (score 4):

$2,3$ are relatively prime so $2|(m-n)$, $3|(m-n)$ implies $6|(m-n)$ meaning $m\equiv n \mod 6$.

Answer (score 0):

If $c$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$, then $c$ is a multiple of their least common multiple $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)$.

Apply this to $c=m-n$ and $a=2$ and $b=3$.